# Message Embed not Sending, Possible Else Error

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make something where if a staff member tried to unban someone that isn't banned, the bot would send him an embed: "That member is not banned". But it doesn't seem to work. Any help?

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMFFn.png)

Comment: Please do not post images, the code should be within the question.

Comment: Your `if` statement is outside the for loop, tab it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent the if else conditions into for loop. You can try this:

```
for ban_entry in banned_users:
    user = ban_entry.user

    if ():
        ...
    else:
        ...
```